# While creating New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy I am getting below error and I can't disable MFA in my organization

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Power shell script

```
WRITE-HOST "Createing access policy "
$userCredential = Get-Credential
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $userCredential
New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity OnlineMeeting-policy10 -AppIds "appid" -Description "OnlineMeeting"
Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -PolicyName OnlineMeeting-policy10 -Global
```

Error details :

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams: Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $userCredential
    
One or more errors occurred.

(AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'.
    
Trace ID: ce73772c-3440-4da1-afa2-c60787dd6700
Correlation ID: 16b7f655-d1c8-4058-a380-22d01fee233e
Timestamp: 2022-08-16 09:40:51Z)
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable MFA in your organization via PowerShell

```
    Install-Module MSOnline
    Connect-MsolService
    #To disable MFA for a single user
    Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "UPN" | Set-MsolUser -StrongAuthenticationRequirements @()
```

***You can also try doing via portal ->Azure portal -> azure Ad -> users -> Per-User MFA***

[image]

Select username and disable like below

[image]

Make sure to disable **Security Defaults**, to make MFA disabled

[image]

***References:***

[Enable/Disable MFA in Azure Active Directory](https://theitbros.com/enable-disable-mfa-in-azure-active-directory/)  by *Cyril Kardashevsky*

[Error: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator](https://cloudblue.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/44001883537--office-365-error-due-to-a-configuration-change-made-by-your-administrator-or-because-you-moved-to)

Comment: Hi Imrankhan,  Can I do anything without disabling MFA?

Comment: Please attempt to turn off MFA since if it is on, it will cause a rule to be triggered and an action (such as a sudden location change) to be taken and its moves to a new location check the above references

Comment: If I turn off MFA it's working as expected. but I dont want to turn off MFA, is there any other way to create policy?